# Mapping Income by Neighborhood with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, choropleth

I have the mean income data for different section of Oklahoma City and I'm trying to create a choropleth of the city. Here is the data.

```
library(acs)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(UScensus2010)
library(spdep)
library(RColorBrewer)

# Use your census API key (You'll need to get your own API key)
#http://api.census.gov/data/key_signup.html
api.key.install(key="c369cd6ed053a84332caa62301eb8afe98bed825")

# Load in Shape File (You'll need to download this file from the census)
#ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2013/TRACT/tl_2013_40_tract.zip
geodat<-readShapePoly((""), proj4string=CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83'))

geodat<-geodat[geodat$COUNTYFP==109,]

# Tract Level Data
mdat<-geodat@data

# American Community Survey Data: Median HH Income for OK Census Tracts
ok.counties=geo.make(state="OK", county="Oklahoma", tract="*")
ok.income<-acs.fetch(geography=ok.counties, table.number="B19013", endyear=2013)

# Merge Data Sets 
geo_dat<-geography(ok.income)
var_dat<-as.data.frame(estimate(ok.income))
acs_data<-cbind(geo_dat,var_dat)
mdat2<-merge(mdat,acs_data,by.x="TRACTCE", by.y= "tract")

#cut data
mdat2$cut <- cut(mdat2$B19013_001, breaks = c(5000, 200000, by = 10000))
map <- mdat2[, 11:12]

#create map
 okc <- ggplot(mdat2, aes(x = INTPTLON, y = INTPTLAT, fill = B19013_001)) +
                  geom_map(aes(fill=cut), map=map)
```

I'm new to ggplot2 and can't seem to get it to work properly. I was able to create a choropleth using spplot but I would like to make one with ggplot so that I can layer it with other maps.

edit: Forgot to include that I am attempting to create a choropleth with median income as the fill. Median income is B19013_001 in the mdat2 data frame. The INTPTLON vector is the longitude coordinates for the different sections of the city and INTPTLAT is the latitude coordinates.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPcs4.png)  is an example of a plot I created in sppolot. I am trying to make something similar in ggplot

Here are the first 10 observations from mdat2:

```
  TRACTCE STATEFP COUNTYFP       GEOID NAME.x          NAMELSAD MTFCC FUNCSTAT   ALAND AWATER    INTPTLAT
1  100100      40      109 40109100100   1001 Census Tract 1001 G5020        S 2141969      0 +35.5207581
2  100200      40      109 40109100200   1002 Census Tract 1002 G5020        S 3349288      0 +35.5039838
3  100300      40      109 40109100300   1003 Census Tract 1003 G5020        S 2098254      0 +35.5123370
4  100400      40      109 40109100400   1004 Census Tract 1004 G5020        S 2593440      0 +35.5004315
5  100500      40      109 40109100500   1005 Census Tract 1005 G5020        S 2734867      0 +35.5006179
6  100600      40      109 40109100600   1006 Census Tract 1006 G5020        S  551754      0 +35.5040878
      INTPTLON                                       NAME.y state county B19013_001
1 -097.5315537 Census Tract 1001, Oklahoma County, Oklahoma    40    109      33440
2 -097.5546474 Census Tract 1002, Oklahoma County, Oklahoma    40    109      29338
3 -097.5259348 Census Tract 1003, Oklahoma County, Oklahoma    40    109      85592
4 -097.4855750 Census Tract 1004, Oklahoma County, Oklahoma    40    109      21084
5 -097.5037840 Census Tract 1005, Oklahoma County, Oklahoma    40    109      23411
6 -097.5172200 Census Tract 1006, Oklahoma County, Oklahoma    40    109      62857
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? And please include some of your data (may be simulated). Very few people are going to get passwords/API-keys in order to answer your question.One point: don't use `data$column` inside aes-calls. It's unnecessary, especially when everything comes from mdat2 already.

Comment: @Heroka I added an image of a choropleth I created using spplot. I'm trying to recreate something like this in ggplot. How can I add sample data for something like this? I could include my API key if that will make it easier. The important vectors in the mdat2 data frame are INTPTLON, INTPTLAT and B19013_001 which are represent the longitude, latitude and median income respectively.

Comment: so, what is the error / hangup?

Comment: Looks like your INTPLON / INTPLAT are points--you will need to map full polygon geometries, not just points (with the right data structure, ggplot can plot automatically without explicit x / y args). There are several tutorials online about how to prep spatial data, like http://goo.gl/PkeHR6--see if you can get `geom_map` to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that works with ggplot:

```
library(acs)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(UScensus2010)
library(spdep)
library(RColorBrewer)


library(dplyr)
library(scales)

# Use your census API key (You'll need to get your own API key)
#http://api.census.gov/data/key_signup.html
api.key.install(key="c369cd6ed053a84332caa62301eb8afe98bed825")

# Load in Shape File (You'll need to download this file from the census)
#ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2013/TRACT/tl_2013_40_tract.zip

## load, subset shapefile
geodat<-readShapePoly("/home/aksel/Downloads/ohio//tl_2013_40_tract.shp", proj4string=CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83'))
geodat<-geodat[geodat$COUNTYFP==109,]

## fortify for ggplot digestion
geodat.f<-fortify(geodat,region="GEOID")

# American Community Survey Data: Median HH Income for OK Census Tracts
ok.counties=geo.make(state="OK", county="Oklahoma", tract="*")
ok.income<-acs.fetch(geography=ok.counties, table.number="B19013", endyear=2013)


# Merge Data Sets 
geo_dat<-geography(ok.income)
var_dat<-as.data.frame(estimate(ok.income))
acs_data<-cbind(geo_dat,var_dat)
acs_data$id<- paste("40109", acs_data$tract, sep = "")

## from dplyr
mapdata<-left_join(geodat.f,acs_data)

ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = mapdata, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group,
                                    fill = B19013_001), color = "black", size = 0.5)+
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Reds", labels = comma,
                       breaks = pretty_breaks(n = 10), values = c(1,0)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) +
  theme_nothing(legend = TRUE) +
ggtitle('Map of 40109')
```

Which yields:
[image]

Comment: For your information, I am working on a package that draws census boundaries on ggmap with a single function `geom_boundary( )` , https://github.com/GL-Li/ggtiger. Hope it is useful to you.